# How to esign on pdf using itextsharp and PKCS7 in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, digital-signature

I want to esign on pdf using itextsharp in asp.net MVC. This is the xml which is response of webservice when I send hash value of pdf. So I have to sign on pdf using PKCS7 of this xml. For this they (webservice provider) said I have to decode this in base64 then sign on pdf. I am very new for esign so much serach on google but can't find solution.

this is xml

```
    <EsignResponse errCode="NA" errMsg="NA" resTs="2017-11-22T16:49:03.615" status="1" txn="707817b3-d5d1-4476-b5b8-4e2cfb6db506">
  <Pkcs7Resp>MIILNQYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIILJjCCCyICAQExDzANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFADALBgkqhkiG9w0BBwGg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</Pkcs7Resp>
  <UserX509Certificate>-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----</UserX509Certificate>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>cYvWAo4bLg1nGW4PyxtUCA8X4mg=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>Ojo7tfNdMUguTpQcd/zXWqwQ+U4MeUs8b1QeqPTou3h6CTLKKpg5idKU1JSyhvbzshLjtXQRJNe/
opK+sG3W+CRlAwL6gffkcejd5bQFOFjtslug8Mex0lP/peXbfwRb0n218GfYGLSTnY7Fg1mRF6XL
/+ewWpa0zNtUvXNJ4JtjHesjGIv9OFq3B2RWTuJSGv2UqY1/C0buj4jZ26GdWkgwwRYSDjr+9ZE1
FIVITcN5k/MPJGVSiHCNmEwBJHhhr01v+gmxw8fjufZpM3DlX+aXTLwLRp5yvu055SZikTC4Hk/f
G6OB/cNnmssGa/1afuDyxRA/mE3ox7OCopQ+3A==</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509SubjectName>CN=eSign,OU=NICSI,O=NIC,L=New Delhi,ST=Delhi,C=IN</X509SubjectName>
        <X509Certificate>MIIDXTCCAkWgAwIBAgIEOKGXSjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBfMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJTjEOMAwGA1UE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</X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</EsignResponse>
```

this is my code

```
var client = new WebClient();
    var response = new client.UploadString("http://webserviceaddress/EsignTest/rest/Esign/EsignRequestResponse/", "POST", xd.InnerXml.ToString()); // in xd.innerxml i am sending hash value of a pdf file on which I have to esign.
    using (var reader = new response.ToString())
                            {
                                var xml = XElement.Load(reader);
                                var value = xml.Attribute("status").Value;
                                if (value == "1")
                                {
                                    var resultString = "";
                                    XElement OtpRequestXML = xml.Descendants("Pkcs7Resp").Single();
                                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                                    XmlNode xmlFinalNode = xmlDoc.ImportNode(OtpRequestXML.ToXmlNode(), true);

                                    resultString = xmlFinalNode.InnerText;

                                    resultString = resultString.Replace('-', '+');
                                    resultString = resultString.Replace('_', '/');

                                    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(resultString);   


                                    string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);


                                    string NewFileName = RandomString(5) + fileName;
                                    string destination = Server.MapPath("~/WriteReadData/" + "signed_" + NewFileName);

        // here i stop unable to understand how I go further


                                    TempData["AlertMessage"] = " esign successfully on pdf.";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    TempData["AlertMessage"] = " There is someting wrong.";
                                }
```

Comment: *"when I send hash value of pdf"* - which PDF? You are aware that you do not need a signature of the *original* PDF but of the it with some changes preparing it for inserting the P7 signature container, aren't you?

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[] sigbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Pkcs7Resp").InnerText);
byte[] paddedSig = new byte[8192];
Array.Copy(sigbytes, 0, paddedSig, 0, sigbytes.Length);
PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
dic2.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSig).SetHexWriting(true));
appearance.Close(dic2);
```

this is the code to add signature 
please refer https://github.com/emudhra/eSign-India-Integration-CSharp/blob/eSign-2.0/eSign.cs